# How do you use two aggregate functions for separate tables in a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if this is a noob question!

I have two tables - a movie and a comment table.

I am trying to return output of the movie name and each comment for that movie as long as that movie has more than 1 comment associated to it.

Here are my tables

```
test_movies=# SELECT * FROM movie;
 id |                name                | rating | release_date | original_copy_location
----+------------------------------------+--------+--------------+------------------------
  1 | Cruella                            |      9 | 2021-05-28   |                      4
  7 | Shutter Island                     |      9 | 2010-02-19   |                      4
  9 | Grown Ups                          |      7 | 2010-06-25   |                      4
 11 | Guardians of the Galaxy: Volume 1  |      8 | 2014-09-01   |                      4
 14 | The RIng                           |      8 | 2002-10-18   |                      4
 17 | Digimon: The Movie                 |      6 | 2000-01-10   |                      4
 19 | Star Wars Episode 1                |      5 | 1999-06-21   |                      4
 20 | Ghosts Of Mars                     |      5 | 1998-09-15   |                      4
  5 | Interstellar                       |      8 | 2014-11-07   |                      1
 10 | Mean Girls                         |      8 | 2004-04-30   |                      1
 12 | Captain America: The First Avenger |      7 | 2011-07-22   |                      1
 15 | Get Out                            |      6 | 2017-02-24   |                      1
  6 | The Dark Knight                    |     10 | 2008-07-18   |                      2
 16 | Pokemon: The First Movie           |      5 | 1998-11-10   |                      2
 18 | The Last Dance                     |      8 | 2020-05-01   |                      2
  8 | Just Go With It                    |      8 | 2011-02-11   |                      3
 13 | The Blair Witch Project            |      8 | 1999-08-29   |                      3
(17 rows)


    test_movies=# SELECT * FROM comments;
 c_id |                      c_comment       | c_movie | c_user
------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------
    1 | testing comment 1                    |      16 |      4
    2 | testing comment 1                    |       1 |      1
    3 | testing comment 1                    |       1 |      2
    4 | testing comment 1                    |       8 |      5
    5 | testing comment 1                    |       6 |      3
    6 | testing comment 1                    |      12 |      2
    7 | testing comment 1                    |      20 |      3
    8 | testing comment 1                    |      16 |      5
    9 | testing comment 1                    |      17 |      4
   10 | testing comment 1                    |      12 |      2
  
(10 rows)
```

Output im trying to get is this:

```
name                    |      c_comment       
------------------------+-------------------------------------
Cruella                 | testing comment 1
Curella                 | testing comment 1
Pokemon:The First Movie | testing comment 1
Pokemon:The First Movie | testing comment 1
Captain America         | testing comment 1
Captain America         | testing comment 1
```

The problem with my queries is that I can't figure out how to return both the movie name and comment associated with it using aggregate functions.

If I use the count in the first select statement it returns all rows:

```
SELECT m.name, c.c_comment FROM movie m, comments c WHERE m.id = c.c_movie GROUP BY m.name, c.c_comment HAVING COUNT(m.name) >= 1;
```

If I try the below subquery I get the error - `ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`

```
SELECT m.name, c.c_comment FROM movie m, comments c WHERE m.id = c.c_movie AND(SELECT m.name, COUNT(c.c_movie) FROM movie m, comments c WHERE m.id =c.c_movie GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(c.c_movie) > 1);
```

Still a bit new to SQL as I'm a student and having a tough time figuring this query out lol.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use agregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
select m.name, c.c_comment
from movie m
  join comment c
    on c.c_movie = m.id
where exists (select 1 from comments cc where cc.c_movie=m.id group by c_movie having count(*)>1)
```

It's standard sql, but you cannot work with mysql and postgresql at the same time...

Comment: what does the "select 1" and "exists" mean in WHERE clause of this query? Just out of curiosity as I am not sure what either means so far in my learning lol. Oh i am using Postgresql atm - It works though

Comment: The subselect filters comments which have more than 1 record for the movie (`having count(*)>1`). If that condition meets, you can return whatever (for example 1), because the `exists ` clause just checks if some row is returned by the subselect.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, makes sense to me know. The 1 acts as just a true/false because the exist keyword is checking to make sure there is a value there. And if there is the condition is true. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer is valid please mark it as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!

```
select m.name, c.c_comment
from movie m join
     (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by c_movie) as cnt
      from comment c
     ) c
     on c.c_movie = m.id
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I will look into this Gordon. I found the docs on the postgresql site where they talk about window functions. Thanks for the heads up